# Photovoltaic systems - typical values of electrical current

Tags: current, inverter, solar-energy

SOLAR PANELS -> CHARGE CONTROLLER -> [shunt A] BANK OF BATTERIES [shunt B] -> INVERTER - AC OUTPUT

What are typical values (to give examples) of electrical current on shunt A (current in on batteries) and on shunt B (current out of batteries), and also at the AC output.

I know that this depends on the application, but I would like to have a better idea of typical values of current in these systems, what values can be reached?

This is for a energy meter project.

Comment: The current coming out of the batteries will generally vary between zero and around 200 Amps, depending on the application. Solar panels usually put out less than 15 Amps or so. At night it may be as low as zero or even have a slight negative current.

Comment: The output from the panels during the day will be affected by clouds and shading according to the location, just two that are independent of the panels themselves.

Comment: A single string of solar cells is likely to deliver about 10A (150mm cells) or 6A (125mm cells). Panels are sometimes added in series up to a few hundred V, still at 10A. You may have several strings in parallel to increase current; but often each has its own charge controller.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have idea of the hole where the wire goes thriugh, what should be the diameter fir 500A DC?